# "Array index in initialiser exceeds array bounds"

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I would like to make use of C99 designated array initialisers to help make my code more self-documenting but I'm running into the problem described below.

Suppose I have a enumeration and an array mapping the enumerants to some other useful data structure, for example:

```
enum { STATE_IDLE = 0, STATE_WORKING, STATE_PANIC };
int32_t const g_stress_levels[3] = {
        [STATE_IDLE] = 10,
        [STATE_WORKING] = 40,
        [STATE_PANIC] = 90
};
```

The above compiles with no warnings with TDM-GCC-32 gcc 4.8.1 and `-std=c99`. The snippet below does not and instead raises the error "array index in initialiser exceeds array bounds".

```
enum { STATE_IDLE = 0, STATE_WORKING, STATE_PANIC, TOTAL_STATES };
int32_t const g_stress_levels[TOTAL_STATES] = {
        [STATE_IDLE] = 10,
        [STATE_WORKING] = 40,
        [STATE_PANIC] = 90
};
```

[The GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) state "the index values must be constant expressions, even if the array being initialized is automatic".
I've always thought however that `enum` is a constant expression, so why might this be the case?

Comment: This code is absolutely valid. [It compiles and runs perfectly using gcc](http://ideone.com/dXnbgH). If your compiler generates an error, it's a bug in your compiler. Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code runs fine, as expected<sup>*</sup>:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ cat px.c
#include <stdint.h>

enum { STATE_IDLE = 0, STATE_WORKING, STATE_PANIC, TOTAL_STATES };
int32_t const g_stress_levels[TOTAL_STATES] = {
        [STATE_IDLE] = 10,
        [STATE_WORKING] = 40,
        [STATE_PANIC] = 90
};

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o px px.c
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$
```

The problem must lie somewhere else. You also check it live [here](http://ideone.com/e.js/DRdRzt).

*<sub>[Can enum member be the size of an array in ANSI-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770314/can-enum-member-be-the-size-of-an-array-in-ansi-c)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

it's not a bug in GCC, but you initializing out of bound.

OK:

```
#define profil_a = 0
#define profil_b = 1
foo_ini [ profil_a, profil_b ];
```

Error:

```
//#define profil_a = 0
#define profil_b = 1
foo_ini [ profil_b ];
```

Fix:

```
//#define profil_a = 0
#define profil_b = 0
foo_ini [ profil_b ];
```